# How to add color to specific text in excel output file using powershell

Tags: microsoft-excel, dns, powershell, ping, colors

I have written a script to check the nslookup for each server and export the details to Excel

Please help me on How to add color to specific text in the Excel output

**CODE**

```
$result = foreach($Server in $Servers) {
    $addresses = try {
        [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($Server).IPAddressToString
    }
    catch {
        "Server IP cannot resolve"
    }
    foreach($address in $addresses) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Server    = $Server
            IPAddress = $address
        }
    }
}

$result | Export-Excel ....
```

Comment: Is the text the entire content of a given cell or just part of it?

Comment: I will get the output as Server cannot resolve IP in the B column, I want to add red color code to that text in column B

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - I will get the output as Server cannot resolve IP in the B column, I want to add red color code to that text in column B